# iOS - app crashes after update, clean install is OK - how to debug this?

Tags: ios, testing

I have a problem with one of my apps. I have released major update, that also changed app bundle data and core functionality.

Users, that install this app version as an update, got a startup-crash. Clean installs seems to be correct (at least users with this problem says so, after deleting app and doing clean install, problem is gone).

From Apple crash log, the log is weird, because the stack trace is incorrect. It says, that crash is in method A that is called from B. However, method A is never called from B in my code.

Is there a way how to debug this? Can I somehow install (retrieve) previous version of app and test update with XCode debugger running? I dont have codes for the previous version, so I cannot do its build manually and test it.

Comment: As far as I see, the reasons for a crash with update only must be the data which is stored by the previous version and now is read by the new app version. I'd look into settings stored in user defaults, core data issues, any other data the app writes to the file system. Regarding an older version: Do you have an archive from the last app submission? (Xcode-Menu: Window > Organizer)

Comment: @RainerSchwarze Yes, I should have older version in organizer. Regarding data, I have local database and its update scripts, that update it. Other local data are caches, but those should not be affected, since they are tested. Only thing that changed in data is app bundle and I would expect that they are "rewritten" with a new version. Or am I wrong and data from bundle are cached somewhere and needed to be deleted?

Comment: If you have an archived version, you might be able to export an app from it, which can be installed on your device. Then maybe you can run the current one and see what happens. Are you sure, that the update scripts run at the right time? Maybe the DB is accessed before it gets updated?

Comment: I have tried to export old version, works fine. However, no problem occured at my devices. I have tried changing various parameters and do the update. Since the DB is updated during its initialization, there is no way, how it can get access DB before this.